# ruby Unexpected keyword else error

Tags: ruby

I have this ruby program to parse a CSV file. I am missing a endif somewhere and I cannot figure out.

```
require 'csv'
prevrow=nil
newarray=Array.new
CSV.foreach("\\\\192.168.0.1\\fe18cb0618cabd41\\ninjatrader\\uniqueside.csv", col_sep: ',') do |row|

  if(prevrow==nil)
    # do nothing
    newarray<<row
    prevrow=row

  elsif (prevrow!=nil and row[0]!=prevrow[0] )
    # do something

    newarray<<row
    prevrow=row
    @@count=1
  elsif(prevrow!=nil and row[0]=prevrow[0] and  @@count<4)
    puts "new date"
    newarray<<row
    prevrow=row
    @@count++
  end
end
```

> removesamedirctiontop4.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else
>   removesamedirctiontop4.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: You didn't end the 'if' within the first 'elsif'

Comment: I fixed the code but I am still getting error removesamedirctiontop4.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end

Comment: it was the autoincrement that was causing the incorrect error message

Comment: There's some pretty serious anarchy here when it comes to code layout. Please, *especially* when posting questions, get things orderly. Use a **consistent indentation style**. Ruby tradition is two spaces in each block, [as recommended by many style guides](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Consistent indentation helps you visually spot potential syntax errors.

Comment: note: The last `elsif` has this: `row[0]=prevrow[0]`. You are using an `=` and not `==`

Comment: There is no `else` in your code...?

Answer (score 6):

`@count++` is not valid ruby.  The final "plus" is expecting another parameter and thinks it's on the next line, so the line ends up being interpreted as...

```
`@count + +end`
```

So you have an invalid statement and you lose an `end`.

Change the offending line to

```
@count += 1
```